# How long are rights preserved if the domain controller goes down

Tags: linux, windows, domain-controller, network-attached-storage

I have a network with one domain controller and 2 NAS-servers (running on a built-in Linux OS). Permissions to the files on the NAS servers are handled through AD rights.  I want to bring the DC down for a short while (up to half an hour) and need to know if people who already are accessing the NAS-servers are still able to do that while the DC is down (as long as they don't logoff, reboot etc their machines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the NAS is using Kerberos, you should probably be fine. You can use `klist` to see what Kerberos tickets specific clients have. This includes expiration time. It should give you a rough idea of how long you generally have.

That said, only having 1 DC is dangerous. You should always have a minimum of two. In addition to mitigating the danger of a failure, it also would make situations like this go away.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me for of the Kerboros expiration time. Completely forgot about that.
A second DC is not in the cards, alas.